# Fitting a function

Tags: fitting

I defined and evaluated a function

```
Max2[t_?NumericQ] := Log[Abs[-1 + First[Maximize[sol1[[2]][x, t], 0 <= x <= L, x]]]];
```

Now, I expect this to be close to a straight line as a function of $t$, so I would like to get the best slope from a fit.

Looking at the reference website, I don't understand how to linearly fit a function.

Comment: You have provided incomplete information. How come on earth we will know what `sol1[[2]][x, t]` or the value of `x` are? Without this info no one can address the problem here.

Comment: One way to find a linear fit to a function is by taking the derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a vaguely straight function like you say yours is:

```
Plot[Log[t], {t, 50, 100}]
```

[image: logplot]

You could fit a line to it by sampling a bunch of points:

```
data = Table[{t, Log[t]}, {t, 50, 100}];
```

And fitting a line through those:

```
fit = Fit[data, {1, t}, t]
(*  3.2732 + 0.0136576 t  *)
```

Or you could minimise the integral of the square difference (i.e. least squares) directly yourself:

```
fit2 = a + b t /. Last@NMinimize[Integrate[(a + b t - Log[t])^2, {t, 50, 100}], {a, b}]
(*  3.27497 + 0.0136447 t  *)
```

They both give similar results:

```
Plot[{Log[t], fit, fit2}, {t, 50, 100}]
```

[image: logfit]

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I extract the slope from the output fit, without making the derivative?

Comment: You could use a rule `fit /. m_ t + c_ :> m` or pick out the right part `fit[[2, 1]]`